# What is the code for numeric input key on tablet?

Tags: angular, keyboard-events, tablet

I'm developing an Angular app which is meant to run only on tablets. I want to bind an event to trigger when the user hits the enter button on a numeric input. Anyway I don't know the keycode of that button.
On a regular keyboard the enter button is 13, but not on number pad for input of type number.

for reference I have something like this in my angular app:

`<input ... type="number" (keypress)="onEnter($event)">`

and the function (at the moment is bound to the enter key of the reguar keyboard) looks like this:

```
onEnter(e) {
    const keycode = (e.keycode ? e.keycode : e.which);
    if (keycode === 13) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

In this case the keycode for the enter key is 13. So what number is the keycode for the enter key of a number pad on a tablet?

I would log it to console, but since I'm on a tablet I cant do that, or better I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can alert it instead.

Comment: I tried to alert it but as soon as I tap that button it skips anything and goes on. I tried also to call e.preventDefault() but nothing happens. 
Do you know if somewhere there is a sort of table that tells what charcode it is bound to?

Comment: You could also display key code values in the component by capturing the value into an array and using *ngFor to loop over the array.